# permission denied in android 10 & 11 when use "/system/bin/sh" in ProcessBuilder

Tags: python, android, android-permissions, android-10.0, android-11

I'm working with Python within my android app and I want to write a command :

```
ProcessBuilder p=null;
    Process x=null;
    try {
        p = new ProcessBuilder("/system/bin/sh", "-c",command);
        Map<String, String> env = p.environment();
        for(Map.Entry<String, String> variable:envirounmentVariables.entrySet()){
              env.put(variable.getKey(), variable.getValue());
        }
        p.redirectErrorStream(true);

        x = p.start();

        try {
            x.waitFor();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    try {
        return readFully(x.getInputStream());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
public static String readFully(InputStream is) throws IOException {
    
      String result1 = CharStreams.toString(new InputStreamReader(
              is, Charsets.UTF_8));
      return  result1;
    }
```

but the result is :
**/system/bin/sh: /data/user/0/com.nepk.cidra/files/python/bin/python: Permission denied**

Even though I got all the permissions that Android 11 needs :
in manifest :

```
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    tools:ignore="ScopedStorage" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />


    android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
    android:preserveLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```

and permissions in real time :
"ACTION_MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION"
and every

Knowing that I have tried storing Python files in all possible folders to store them in Android 11 and the result is the same .
Also, in the application, I can download and read files within Android 11, but only in this case I get this result .

Note that this code works fine with Android under 10 (api < 29)

Comment: Those permissions are not for such system directories.  Also not for api < 29. /system/bin is just not readable on 11+.

Comment: On 10+ i ment..

Comment: What is the solution in your opinion ? What can I replace it with?

Comment: I have no idea what you wanna accomplish. You did not tell that.